# Composer - copy vendor files from dev to production is OK?

Tags: amazon-web-services, composer-php

I'm using composer for AWS SDK.

Is it OK to install the SDK on a dev pc (windows) and copy the vendor directory to production or must I install composer on the production server (linux) and get the libraries installed there by composer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Moving the whole project around to another path or even different computer should work fine, given that all paths generated for autoloading etc are relative.